# Prompt command starting in the wrong folder

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, prompt

I am currently facing an issue I do not know how to track.

I put the start-in option of a prompt command to :

```
C:\Users\XXX\Downloads
```

Then apply and finally when I open the prompt command, it starts in:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents>
```

I remember one year ago I modify the registry to start in documents folder, and this is certainly the reason why it overloads the prompt command value I set up. But I am clearly not able anymore to know which key it is ... does someone have an idea?

Comment: [Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895966/changing-default-startup-directory-for-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open up registry editor by typing `regedit` in the search box, and then clicking on the link up top.
2. Navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and search for the string `Autorun` in the left window. If that string does not exist yet, create it. Double-click it afterwards and add the new directory path in the following way: `CD /d C:\Users\XXX\Documents`
3. If you would like the command prompt to open in the Documents folder, use this string instead: 
   `CD /d C:\Users\XXX\Documents`
4. Close the registry editor, and then open the command prompt to check your work.